# Add Babel to Typescript React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I've created a React app with Typescript support using [create-react-app](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter).

I'm targeting ES5 with the Typescript transpiler, which gives me support for ES6 syntax, but doesn't add the polyfills for the enhanced Array features etc of ES6 like Babel does.

Is there a way to use both Typescript and Babel?

i.e. .ts > ES6 > babel > ES5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I go about it:

1. `create-react-app your-app`
2. `cd your-app`
3. `tsc --init` (initialize your Typescript config file)
4. `mkdir ts` (create a `ts` folder to store your Typescript source code)
5. Delete existing files in your `src` folder.
6. Edit your `tsconfig.json` file and set the following options:

   `"target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "outDir": "./src",
    "rootDir": "./ts",
    "moduleResolution": "node"`
7. `tsc -w -p .` (start Typescript compiler in watch mode)
8. `npm start` (start React development script)

Now, create `index.tsx` in your `ts` folder and start building up your app. As you add and save files, they'll get compiled by Typescript compiler and copied into the `src` folder, where Babel/CRA will pick it up and transpile it to whatever CRA typically does. This method preserves the CRA (create-react-app) project structure, doesn't require substituting the `react-scripts`, etc. You just code in Typescript, the Typescript compiler will compile it to modern Javascript and CRA does the rest.

Caveat: While `tsc` will create the Javascript files in its output folder (`src`), you'll have to manually copy your `css`, images, and other static resources.

Answer (score 0):

> add the polyfills for the enhanced Array features etc of ES6 like Bable does.

Babel doesn't do that. `core-js` does that. You can use core-js with TypeScript. Just add the following to your code:

```
import 'core-js'
```

## More

- [Covered in the `lib.d.ts` option](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#polyfill-for-old-javascript-engines)

Comment: Bit of a plug for your Pro only egghead video here @basarat?